# Contiguous memory guarantees with C++ function parameters

Tags: c++, function, memory-management, calling-convention

[Appel [App02]](http://www.cs.princeton.edu/~appel/modern/) very briefly mentions that C (*and presumably C++) provide guarantees regarding the locations of actual parameters in contiguous  memory as opposed to registers when the address-of operator is applied to one of formal parameters within the function block.*

e.g.

```
void foo(int a, int b, int c, int d)
{
    int* p = &a;
    for(int k = 0; k < 4; k++)
    {
       std::cout << *p << " ";
       p++;
    }
    std::cout << std::endl;
}
```

and an invocation such as...

```
foo(1,2,3,4);
```

will produce the following output "1 2 3 4"

My question is ***"How does this interact with calling conventions?"***

For example __fastcall on GCC will try place the first two arguments in registers and the remainder on the stack. The two requirements are at odds with each other, is there any way to formally reason about what will happen or is it subject to the capricious nature of implementation defined behaviour?

[[App02] Modern Compiler Implementation in Java, Andrew w. Appel, Chapter 6, Page 124](http://books.google.com/books?id=JNs6fWkJZbAC&lpg=PA124&ots=i0sYguK2Yb&dq=Appel%20compiler%20C%20address%20of%20register%20function&pg=PA124#v=onepage&q&f=false)

**Update:** I suppose that this question is answered. I think I was wrong to base the whole question on contiguous memory allocation when what I was looking for (and what the reference speaks of) is the apparent mismatch between the need for parameters being in memory due the use of address-of as opposed to in registers due to calling conventions, maybe that is a question for another day.

Someone on the internet is wrong and sometimes that someone is me.

Comment: Actually that `cout` expression is not well defined (because you are changing and requesting `p` in it), so the result might as well be accidental :)

Comment: @DuncanACoulter Surely, this behaviour is an artefact of the given implementation and is not guaranteed by the C/C++ language standards?

Comment: @DuncanACoulter: one simple way would be to have the compiler diagnose that the calling convention is at odd with the requirement (at the point of definition of the function), since we're talking C / C++ here though... I'd rather not venture on this territory.

Comment: @filmor I have edited the question to no longer use a single output expression. The fundamental question still remains however.

Comment: @aix That is indeed a possibility, sometimes it is possible to get an unambiguous interpretation of the rules and that is what I am hoping for here.

Comment: Now that you've given a link to the text of the book, we can see that it says nothing of the sort; which is good, since such an assertion would be wrong. Neither C nor C++ specify how separate objects are laid out in memory; the only guarantees are for structure and array members.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First of all your code doesn't always produce 1, 2, 3, 4. Just check this one: http://ideone.com/ohtt0
Correct code is at least like [this](http://ideone.com/f72XB):

```
void foo(int a, int b, int c, int d)
{
    int* p = &a;
    for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++)
    {
        std::cout << *p;
        p++;
    }
}
```

So now let's try with `fastcall`, [here](http://ideone.com/bBqnc):

```
void __attribute__((fastcall)) foo(int a, int b, int c, int d)
{
    int* p = &a;
    for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++)
    {
        std::cout << *p << " ";
        p++;
    }
}

int main()
{
        foo(1,2,3,4);
}
```

Result is messy: `1 -1216913420 134514560 134514524`

So I really doubt that something can be guaranteed here.

Comment: The move from a single expression to a loop must have been made while you were formatting your reply.

Comment: I'll accept implementation level disproof by counter-example as presented here. This seems to be highly implementation specific. Pity there does not seem to be a way to establish how the requirements will interact beforehand without resorting to exploratory testing.

Comment: @DuncanACoulter I don't think this is a requirement. Many ABIs x64, alpha, itanium etc. pass/passed the first N arguments in registers as a matter of course. The only scenario I can think of where you'd think you'd need it would be varargs but with functionality like register windows you wouldn't necessarily need it there. I suspect either Appel is mistaken, out of date or you misread or misunderstood the statement. Maybe you could get a better answer if you quote what he said. Even if it is true, your code depends on the direction of stack growth and the order in which parameters are pushed.

Comment: @Logan Capaldo Updated question to include link to exact quote via Google Books.

Comment: @DuncanACoulter: the language standards (for both C and C++) are quite clear that pointer arithmetic is only valid if both the initial pointer and the result are within the same array object.

Comment: @Mike Seymour I see... nonetheless the use of registers would still be invalidated by the behaviour triggered by the & operator which would still lead to a conflict between the ABI and calling convention

Comment: @DuncanACoulter not necessarily. The caller can pass a in a register as per the API, and the function prologue can allocate space on the stack and copy it there so I can take the address of the variable in the body of the function. In fact, it has to work this way or else the types of function pointers and the like would have to include whether or not the address of a parameter was taken in the body of the function or not. This would hardly scale for separate compilation or dynamic linking and taking the address of a parameter should not change the interface of the function.

Comment: @DuncanACoulter: using `&` will force the compiler to make sure the object is placed in memory, whether or not it was passed in registers. There's no conflict as such, and the ABI/calling convention isn't changed; there's just a bit of extra work to do within the function.

Comment: @DuncanACoulter The quote from the book you linked does not at all say anything about contiguous memory. It even says "An industrial-strength compiler must assign provisional locations to formals and locals, and decide later which of them should really go in registers", explicitly allowing for some things to be in registers and others not and saying nothing about contiguity. I think you have misunderstood the text here.

Comment: @Logan Capaldo You are right there is no garauntee about contiguity, perhaps I should re-edit the question title. However the body of my question states two things. Firstly the use of & indicates that the parameter should be in memory and secondly a calling convention may require it to be in a register. I suppose no harm can come from it being in both places?

Comment: @DuncanACoulter no harm but no meaning either. `fastcall` is fast because storing in register is faster than on stack. Compiler can decide to store local variable in register. How & would work them? I guess compiler copies it to memory so that it can have an address. Anyway I really don't think it is worth digging.

Comment: The first example does not necessarily work. For example, on x86 and x64 the stack grows down so it prints `1` and then a bunch of garbage. On my system changing `p++` to `p--` does print `1 2 3 4` but I'm not claiming it's a correct thing to do.

Comment: @AndrewMedico of course not, I never claim it does. I put it as a sample that might work for wide range of users, to demonstrate that you can actually get into stack if you really-really want to. It is not example of what you should really do.

Answer (score 2):

There is nothing in the standard about calling conventions or how parameters are passed.

It is true that if you take the address of one variable (or parameter) that one has to be stored in memory. It doesn't say that the value cannot be passed in a register and then stored to memory when its address is taken.

It definitely doesn't affect other variables, who's addresses are not taken.

Answer (score 1):

The C++ standard has no concept of a calling convention. That's left for the compiler to deal with.

In this case, if the standard **requires** that parameters be contiguous when the address-of operator is applied, there's a conflict between what the standard requires of your compiler and what you require of it.

It's up to the compiler to decide what to do. I'd think most compilers would give your requirements priority over the standard's, however.

Answer (score 0):

Your basic assumption is flawed. On my machine, `foo(1,2,3,4)` using your code prints out:

> 1 -680135568 32767 4196336

Using `g++ (Ubuntu 4.4.3-4ubuntu5) 4.4.3` on 64-bit x86.